# How to create a box with header with css styling?

Tags: html, css

How can I create a box with a coloured "heading area" that has a shadow on the bottom just like this example on the right sidebar of this website: [Box with heading on this website](http://ammibalustrades.com.au/about-us)

This website uses images to create this effect. I would like to use pure CSS3 and HTML5 to achieve this.

I have tried looking for this on Google, but I can't find it anywhere. I'm assuming that I am calling it the wrong thing, that is why I cannot find it. Also, I've tried using a table with two cells, but it does not work out right and I cannot create or place the shadow correctly.

I would like my box to be exactly the same as the example except that I would change the colours.

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to use borders for a triangular mask, and underneath use a background gradient.

Check out my code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ldHIn)

[The updated version](http://codepen.io/pjurczynski/pen/KLvFn). For pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`) you had to make some space for the border (1px on left and right).

Remember that the tricky part is with adjusting the width with this sidebar. First thing to change is the sidebar class, then you should match the borders for the pseudo element `:after`.

Comment: Hi Merstzik, Your solution is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I would also like to know how to create the radiused box underneath it to put my sidebar content in?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #nav{
        width:950px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        background:#F4F4F4;
        background:linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#F4F4F4);
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#F4F4F4);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(#FFF,#F4F4F4);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#FFF),to(#F4F4F4));
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#444444')";
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#CCCCCC');
    }
    #nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        width:910px;
        padding:0px;
        padding-left:30px;
        float:left;
    }
    #nav ul li{
        display:inline;
    }
    #nav ul li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#06C;
        padding:8px;
        padding-left:25px;
        padding-right:25px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        float:left;
        margin:5px;
    }
    #nav ul li a:hover{
        color:#FFF;
        background:#666;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a >Home</a></li>
                 <li><a >Profile</a></li>
                 <li><a >About</a></li>
                 <li><a>Contact US</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>
```

let me know if it work for you.

Comment: This solution is actually a very different thing from what I was looking for. It does not answer the question. Regardless, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this effect with CSS3 use `box-shadow`.

For example, check fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PwerX/

More documentation check this link, it helped me!

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Have fun!